# Cross-platform mobile app & RESTful web service & scoring algorithms - architecture & technologies

Tags: rest, web-applications, mobile, architecture, cross-platform

I am planning to create a cross-platform mobile app that has native-like versions for most mobile platforms, maybe Windows Phone, Android, iOS. It's supposed to store data in DB on server, and the mobile app is mostly for visualizing that (numerical) data.

## Basic usage scenario

- User opens the app
- App data is refreshed via internet connection
- User inputs new data
- New data is sent to server, handled and DB updated
- User's app data is updated according to DB data (*ANIMATION!*)
- User updates settings on his app that alters it's behaviour.

I'm a noob when it comes to designing and programming mobile apps + web services alone, so I'm hoping you could help me with the following questions. Technologies I'm most familiar with: Java EE, Python, HTML/CSS/JS, MySQL, Graphics. Maybe I should go for PhoneGap? Thanks a lot!

1) What cross-platform mobile technology you would recommend?

2) What kind of solution would be most suitable for server/app server? (Estimated code lines < 5000)

3) What's a good place to start learning scoring algorithms?

Please respond if you have answers to any of the questions asked.

[image: Basic structure of the service]

EDIT: found a similar question: [Cross-Platform Mobile Application Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9756547/cross-platform-mobile-application-solution)

Answer (score 2):

@thevangelist: It's a very good question you have raised, all mobile developers face the same problem when we start writing an app. Today there are multiple Open Source Frameworks available in market which are trying to solve the same problem but in different manner.

Based on my research and experience, I would like to recommend below technologies which we can consider while building an mobile apps.

**View**: View is an important part of any mobile apps. When we start building UI/UX we also have consider it's platform design principles. Looking these points I would like to recommend [React Native](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/) for the same.

React Native: It is a Facebook, and Instagram developed JavaScript library used in creating native mobile applications. It allows us to write iOS and Android applications using JSX, a known HTML look-a-like code, and JavaScript. It is based on “Learn once, write anywhere” methodology.

- **Pros**

  - Renders native views with a native behavior and interaction … you’ll end up with a real native application
  - Has a paradigm of “Learn once, write anywhere” where developers only need React and JavaScript to create better application for Andoroid, iOS.
  - Uses native architecture and concept
  - It does not require a WebView
  - CSS Flexbox is used for layout design
- **Cons**

  - Code abstraction leads to bugs and memory leaks
  - Cannot work without the API, which is provided by React Native, technically there’s no fallback like with classic hybrid mobile apps
  - When creating proper native applications, a developer will have more power and control regarding performance tuning
  - React Native is still a new framework so we can’t predict possible problems and downsides

These cons are somewhat negligible, especially if we consider that React Native is empowering more and more native applications with each passing day.

**Data in Transit**: If your app sync data from web services, then there are multiple frameworks available in the market to make our job easier. Please find below some of the most popular JavaScript RESTful Frameworks:

[ACTIONHERO](http://www.actionherojs.com/), [StrongLoop](https://strongloop.com/node-js/loopback-framework/)

**Data at Rest**: You would also be needing offline storage for the sync data. Since we do not have direct support for native SQLite in JavaScript, we need to use some of the React Native SQLite Plugins. Please find below plugins which are available in the market:

[almost](https://github.com/almost/react-native-sqlite), [andpor](https://github.com/andpor/react-native-sqlite-storage), [jbrodriguez](https://github.com//react-native-android-sqlite), [ramsundark5](https://github.com/ramsundark5/react-native-sqlite3), [remobile](https://github.com/remobile/react-native-sqlite)

For **Data at Transit/Data at Rest**, I would like to recommend [Siminov Framework](http://siminov.com) which is available on all the major platforms (Android, iOS, Windows). It also supports hybrid technologies such as [React Native](http://www.actionherojs.com/), [Cordova](http://www.actionherojs.com/), [Xamarin](https://strongloop.com/node-js/loopback-framework/).

**Pros**

- Available on all the major platforms (Android, iOS and Windows)
- Easy to configure, it provides standard xml based structure using we can easily configure our app database
- It allows developers to bind ORM with remote RESTFul web services too
- Also have support for [SQLCipher](https://github.com/andpor/react-native-sqlite-storage) on all the platforms

**Cons**

- Lack of community: Recently they have launched their products on all the major platforms, not many people are using it.
- Since the configuration is based on XML structure which looks pretty old to me. But based on their documentation it was done to support all the major platforms

**Algorithm**: I have found this link [nurlybayevaAMS9](http://www.m-hikari.com/ams/ams-2013/ams-9-12-2013/nurlybayevaAMS9-12-2013.pdf) related to algorithm, hope this may help you.

Comment: Funny thing is that this topic is still as relevant as it was 3 years ago when I originally asked the question. As I understand React native has started really tackling this problem just recently. :)

Comment: @thevangelist: Agree, due to multiple platforms (Android, iOS, Windows) it is very difficult to build/maintain a mobile app. Many frameworks have tried to solve this problem, but unfortunately all have some/other impact on the performance/ui. Last year Facebook has released React Native and since then it has created buzz in market. I personally feel that React Native is the perfect solution for the mobile app development.

Answer (score 1):

1) Never used PhoneGap, although aware of it, but don't forget to consider a simple HTML5 application. If possible, this would save you lots of work and maximize compatibility.

2) You can develop great RESTful webservices with both Java EE (see JAX-RS/Spring) and Python (see django). The choice is really more a matter of personal taste.

Answer (score 1):

Try avoid writing cross platform application.  It is doable using HTML5+jQuery.  But you can never get the same look and feel as native app.  secondly windows, ios and android have their own look and feel and will come up with their own elements.  You can never cater to all three having same code base.  Better is to code using native sdks.